# Can't set focus() on a tabindexed element with children in mobile Safari?

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, accessibility, mobile-safari

As part of some a11y work I've been doing recently on an one page app, I've added code that calls `focus()` on the header of a page whenever a new page loads. This works great on desktop, and gets read out correctly by a screenreader, but completely fails with VoiceOver in mobile Safari.

After hours of debugging and Googling, I discovered that it seems to fail when trying to focus on an element (that is normally not-focusable) with children.

Example code:

```
<div id="header1" tabindex="-1">Hello world</div>
<div id="header2" tabindex="-1">Goodbye <span>cruel cruel</span> world</div>
```

Then enable VoiceOver in Safari, and try to call:

```
document.getElementById('header1').focus();
```

And notice that it gets read, but that

```
document.getElementById('header2').focus();
```

does absolutely nothing, which seems like completely broken behavior to me. Am I doing something fundamentally wrong, or is this a known issue, and is there any way around this without having to resort to focusing on elements without children?

Answer (score 1):

That does sound messed up.  You can try two different things:

1. add a `tabindex="-1"` to the inner `<span>`.  I doubt that will do anything but perhaps the non-focusable nature of the inner element is affecting the parent element.
2. use the undocumented `role="text"` on the outer `<div>`.  That will cause the entire <div> to be treated as one element instead of treating the inner element as a separate VoiceOver "tab stop".  This probably has a better chance at fixing the problem.

```
<div role="text" id="header2" tabindex="-1">Goodbye <span>cruel cruel</span> world</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately neither of those work, and seem to actually break the page further in that it even prevents focusing on the first header after you make those changes.

Comment: The first heading example didn’t have a problem. The code idea was for the second nested one. Changing the second one should have no affect on the first one. If it does, then there’s something else wrong with your code and you’d have to post a more complete example.

Comment: I was actually using the example code snippet above with nothing else on the page when testing your suggestion.

Comment: But my example code was for the 2nd heading.  You said after using it that the first heading stopped working.  That's what doesn't make sense.  Did you change the 1st or 2nd heading?  Changing the 2nd heading to use my example should not affect the first unless there's something else wrong with your code.

Comment: I went back and tested more carefully, and it seems like there's a larger issue of `focus()` not always adjusting the accessibility focus, which was why the 1st heading was no longer getting read out when I thought it should. That said, the text role still doesn't work.